# How Meta Data is different from Custom Fields of POST/PAGE in WordPress

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I am really looking forward to have a clear picture of **Why Meta data is being used for the Posts/Pages?**

I have always been wondering on how Meta data is different from the `Custom Fields` of Posts. I have read about the Meta-Data on certain websites, and got to know that the definition is quite confusing. This goes like:

> Meta data are used to add some more details or data to the posts/pages.

Now, what I feel, is when we add fields to the post type, we are also creating the same details/extra information for the same. Please give some more details in a brief way so that I can understand the difference between **Meta data and Custom Fields** in a POST/PAGE.

Comment: In a WordPress context of post/page/custom post type they *are* the same thing, ie. custom fields for a post = "post meta". You can have meta data for a user however (ie. user meta)... "meta data" is just a generalized term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom field is a visible form element where users can add information. It's presentation.

Meta data are data stored in one of the meta tables for posts, users, terms and so on.

The content of a custom field can be stored as meta data, in a separate table, a text file, on a remote site … wherever you want it.

In most cases, custom fields for posts are stored as post meta data.

Comment: So they're technically same, having minute differences, that is what I've got from your point. Right?

Comment: They can be related, but the "field" is just the form element in HTML, while the "meta data" is an entry in the database.